# External disk takes a long time to appear in Finder

Tags: macos, external-disk, mount

I'm running Mac OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan) and it seems the larger the external disk I plug in, the longer it takes to show up in Finder.

A 2TB disk is taking almost a minute.

If I plug the same disk on a Windows or Linux PC, it shows up instantly.

Why does this happen on Mac? Is there an option or configuration to make the disk show up faster?

Comment: What's the format of the disk?

Comment: What connection protocol? (USB, FireWire, SATA, Thunderbolt)?

Comment: @Allan It's NTFS and I have FUSE for OS X installed.

Comment: @IconDaemon USB

Comment: Is it USB2 or USB3?

Comment: @IconDaemon It's USB 2.0. I thought it could be related to Spotlight, but I disabled it and the problem remains. Also updated FUSE, no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to macOS Sierra, I uninstalled FUSE and ntfs-3g and started using the hidden NTFS support from Apple (through [Mounty](http://enjoygineering.com/mounty/)). The disk now mounts very fast, so I'm assuming it was the NTFS driver.